# How to perform linq query in JsonArray from Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, linq, facebook-c#-sdk

I`m trying to perform a linq query in a friends JsonArray using Facebook C# SDK. So, i try:

```
var facebook = new FacebookWebClient();

dynamic facebookFriends = facebook.Get("me/friends");

JsonArray data = facebookFriends.data;

var friends = data.Where<JsonObject>(d => d["name"].ToString().StartsWith("D"));
```

But in the last line i get the following compile error:

"'Facebook.JsonArray' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Where(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments"

So, how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `Where<JsonObject>` because `JsonArray` is `IEnumerable<JsonValue>`, not `IEnumerable<JsonObject>`.

On the other hand, you don't have to specify the type using `Where<>` extension method:

```
var friends = data.Where(d => d["name"].ToString().StartsWith("D"));
```

This will make `d` variable inside lambda expression be of `JsonValue`.

If you want iterate over `JsonObject` elements only you have to add `OfType` method before `Where` (but I haven't really tested if it works):

```
var friends = data.OfType<JsonObject>().Where(d => d["name"].ToString().StartsWith("D"));
```

Comment: With the first option i got the following compile error in "d["name"]": "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'". The second way works! =D